# Giving new life to a question

Tags: discussion, feature-request

This is not something I want to do, at least not right now, but if I were to do it, I wouldn't  be sure how to.

This mostly applies to "soft-questions" or question that are more opinions than definitive answers, however I could see this being applied to a regular question.

Say I have a question, which is an exact or close duplicate of another one. I will take for sake of example this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/129013/how-do-you-explain-the-concept-of-logarithm-to-a-five-year-old). Now say I've read all or most answers, but I still want some more opinions.

This question is not the oldest, dated april $7$, but still since this date, there have been new users who might not had the chance to see this question pass, and could have a valuable answer/opinion on the matter.

For regular question, maybe the answers posted do not satisfy me entirely or I would like a specific method of solving.

What would be the way of giving like to the question again? I don't think editing the question saying  "Edit Hi I would like new answers to this question" is appropriate (This would feel like hijacking the OP), nor posting it again since it is duplicate.

The only thing I thought about was bounty but new answers are most likely to get burrowed under the most upvoted ones.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use the bounty system. Whether new answers are "buried under the most upvoted ones" depends on the view one chooses. On the "Active" tab the most recently active answer is shown first (I usually browse on that tab). The most highly voted answers only come first if you browse on the "Votes" tab.